# How to remove underline of method when using Nord theme in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm currently using PhpStorm with the Nord Theme and I cannot remove the underlines of http verbs (e.g. `get` and `post`) when using the Nord theme. I tried to unchecked all the items in Settings Inspection but still getting the same result. Please see my screenshot below.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Please let me know if you need any details that is not indicated yet on my post.

Comment: 1) Place caret on such a place (i.e. on `get` in `Route::get`) and invoke quick fix menu (`Alt+Enter` on most keymaps or via light bulb icon using a mouse). Show what do you see. If this style is made by one of the inspections, it should be somehow there (one way or another). Another approach here is to open `Problems` toolwindow for this file: it should list all issues there.

Comment: 2) At the same time (more likely IMO) this could be the actual Color Style issue and not an Inspection. Try this: place caret on such a place (i.e. on `get` in `Route::get`), then invoke `Help | Find Action...` and look for `Jump to Colors and Fonts` action, invoke it. Show the popup menu that it will show you. Right now the suspect is a style for Static Method Call.

Comment: @LazyOne here's the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/Op0jSU8.png

Comment: It seems to be "Magic Member Access" as per your screenshot

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, it fixed my problem. Can you add your answer so I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to unchecked all the items in Settings Inspection but still getting the same result.

**This is unlikely to be an Inspection** as it would normally have some noticeable colour to indicate an error or a warning.

To check that: see if this line will be mentioned in the "Problems" toolwindow (that lists all inspection results found in a current file). Can also use the intentions/actions/quick fix menu (`Alt+Enter` on most keymaps or via light bulb using a mouse): you would see some entries there for that.

---

**Most likely it’s the Nord Color Scheme itself** that highlights certain elements this way.

Do this:

- Place caret on such a place (i.e. on `get` in `Route::get`).
- Then invoke `Help | Find Action...` (`Ctrl+Shift+A` here on Windows keymap).
- Look for the `Jump to Colors and Fonts` action and invoke it.

  [image]
  *(The shortcut here is my custom one; it has none by default)*

It normally will show a list of all currently applied styles so you can see which one is the most applicable and jump to the style to change it.

**As per your screenshot it turns out to be** the "PHP | Identifiers | Magic Method Access" style:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Underlining is part of the color scheme in JetBrains IDEs.

1. Open the settings
2. Search for "color scheme" and pick the "Color Scheme" entry that is a child of "Editor".
3. Search for your language (probably PHP) and click it - the left side of the dialog should show you the color scheme for PHP now.
4. In the list of options, pick *Functions and Methods* / *Declaration*
5. Deselect the checkbox "Inherit values from:..." if it is ticked.
6. Untick the checkbox "Effects" or change the dropdown and color to your liking.

(I compiled these steps using IDEA but they should be applicable to PhpStorm as well.)

Comment: It is already unchecked. Please see this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/o3jA4eU.png