# Different color for HTML tags in Vue SFC after reinstall

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, quasar, sfc

I recently decided to reinstall PhpStorm because I had some bugs in the past. After the reinstallation, I noticed that every HTML-Tag wrapped inside a  tag got an unusual green color.

[image]

The color scheme doesn't affect this behavior:

[image]

I thought the reason would be some wrong or missing plugins, so I checked my MacBook where everything still works fine. All Plugins and themes are the same. The Code on my MacBook is looking like this:

[image]

I would like to configure it, so that's it looks like the code on my MacBook, but I don't find the right settings.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The same on PhpStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11017126686354-Different-color-for-HTML-tags-in-Vue-SFC-after-reinstall

Comment: I have left a comment there yesterday .. but because it has an URL it needs an approval first. Anyway: At quick glance this seems related (same colors): https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10401366555026-How-to-disable-the-TEAL-color-on-the-React-components

Comment: Thank you very much. I had high hopes because it looked exactly like something I was looking for, but apparently it didn't solve the issue :(

Comment: Lets try this: 1) Place the caret on such a "wrong color" place 2) Invoke `Help | Find Action...` (`Ctrl+Shift+A` here on Windows keymap). 3) Look for the `Jump to Colors and Fonts` action and invoke it. This normally will show a list of all currently applied styles so you can see which one is the most applicable and jump to the style to change it (check here for screenshot -- another issue, just the idea -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75814220/783119)

Comment: As mentioned in that thread by WebStorm support: _"JSX tags are colored according to `Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | XML, Custom Tag Name` settings; please try changing the colors there"_ -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11017126686354/comments/11040082351890

Comment: Sorry for bad answering! Solution provided by Elena at my original Post (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11017126686354-Different-color-for-HTML-tags-in-Vue-SFC-after-reinstall)